# How to make sublime text 3's 'SublimeOnSaveBuild' package not compile the file named beginning with '_' prefix

Tags: regex, sass, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

How to make ***sublime text 3***'s **SublimeOnSaveBuild** package not compile the file named beginning with `_` prefix?

For Example. I want ***a.scss*** or ***a_b.scss*** files can be complied when I saving this files. But not include the files such as named ***_a.scss***.

I saw the guide in [github](https://github.com/alexnj/SublimeOnSaveBuild#configuring) is to set the `filename_filter` configuring.

So I create a ***SublimeOnSaveBuild.sublime-settings***.Contents:

```js
{
    "filename_filter": "/^([^_])\\w*.(sass|less|scss)$/"
}
```

I used two `\` , because it seems would saved as a `.sublime-settings` file which format likes JSON.

But it doesn't work.I use JavaScript to test it, it works well !

```js
let reg = /^[^\_]\w*.(sass|less|scss)$/,
 arr = [
  'a.scss',
  '_a.scss',
  'a_b.scss'
 ];
arr.forEach(function( filename ) {
 console.log( filename + '\t' + reg.test(filename) );
});

// a.scss true
// _a.scss false
// a_b.scss true
```

Thanks!

---

I found a solution in [joshuawinn](http://www.joshuawinn.com/ignore-sass-and-less-partials-starting-with-underscore-when-using-sublimeonsavebuild/). But I can't understand why my codes can't work...

```js
{
    "filename_filter": "(/|\\\\|^)(?!_)(\\w+)\\.(css|js|sass|less|scss)$",
    "build_on_save": 1
}
```

Sorry for my poor English !

Comment: I found a solution in [joshuawinn](http://www.joshuawinn.com/ignore-sass-and-less-partials-starting-with-underscore-when-using-sublimeonsavebuild/)

Answer (score 1):

```
let reg = /^(_|)\w*.(sass|less|scss)$/,
    arr = [
        'a.scss',
        '_a.scss',
        'a_b.scss'
    ];
arr.forEach(function( filename ) {
    console.log( filename + '\t' + reg.test(filename) );
});
```

Comment: I mean in SublimeOnSaveBuild package. When I use`\w*`, *sublime text 3* would alert an error "Error trying to parse settings: Invalid escape in Package\User\SublimeOnSaveBuild.sublime-settings:2:24".

Comment: And you code would console: 

a.scss true
_a.scss true
a_b.scss true